# How do I use PhpStorm to edit and debug source code on a local WAMP server?

Tags: wamp, phpstorm

I have a local WAMP server running a project (`c:\wamp\www\myProject`).  I want to edit and debug this project using PhpStorm.  I was thinking I have to create a project in PhpStorm and import my source into it.

I tried using the wizard "New Project from Existing Files..." but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

- In the wizard I selected "Web server installed locally, source files are located under its document root".
- Next page I selected `c:\wamp\www\myProject` for the directory to create the project in.
- Next page I selected `http://localhost` for the URL and named it `MyProjectURL`.
- The next page says, "Specify project web path on your server. It will be appended to the server root URL".  I left this blank because my project is right on the root.  And I checked the checkbox that says, "Review PHP settings" which enabled the "Next" button.
- When I hit "Next", the next page comes up and says, "Failed to determine PHP installation on server `MyProjectURL`" and it gives you the option to add include paths on the server.

I have no idea what to do here:

- Do I need to add include paths?
- Should I just not check the box to Review PHP settings?
- Am I even doing the right thing by using this wizard?

Comment: Just use "File | Open Directory" -- you can configure everything else later when needed. Alternatively, try without that "Review PHP settings" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this tutorial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_configuring_XAMPP) for the configuration specifics (**Integrating XAMPP with the IDE**). WAMP configuration should be similar.

Comment: The link is now broken? Can you fix it or should you remove this answer?